# Why did stackoverflow.com start popping up new windows?

Tags: support, status-norepro, stack-overflow, popups

It's annoying.  It'll make me want to leave.

Comment: Not for me on Safari :)

Comment: It does that only when you're surfing *(ahem)* mature websites at the same time, right?  (On a more serious note, scan for viruses/spyware and look for malicious browser addons.  They like to pop windows.)

Comment: Please post a link to a page that does this, and a screenshot of it in action.  Any other relevant information will help us pin down the problem.

Comment: I haven't seen it either aka `me too me too` because I like to clutter things up and not in any way reassure the OP ;)

Comment: You probably want to virus scan your PC

Comment: i'll make sure to grab the url it sent me to next time it happens.  It wasn't virus, it was sending me to another site in the SO network.

Answer (score 5):

We can't reproduce this and have no other reports of it.